# PHP Error Undefined Offset

Tags: php, undefined, offset

> Getting Notice: Undefined offset: 25 in
>   C:\wamp\www\finalProjectDemo\search.php on line 32

I'm trying to read in from a file and search for a specific name and address within that for output. I know a database would be best. This is for a class assignment I'm giving out that's specifically set to work this way. I believe I almost have it all, but am just getting this problem. Fairly new to PHP.

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// read lines into array
// search array for string
// get 7 lines from there.
$i = 0;
$fileName = "addresses.txt";
$readFile = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$readByLineArray = array();

// Get search string from submission
$searchFirstName = $_POST['searchFirstName'];
$searchLastName = $_POST['searchLastName'];
$searchFirstNameSuccess = 0;
$searchLastNameSuccess = 0;

while (!feof($readFile))
{
    $readByLineArray[$i] = fgets($readFile);

//echo "$readByLineArray[$i] read from array position $i";
//echo "<br />";
$i++;
}
fclose($readFile);

$arrLength = count($readByLineArray);
$currentArrayPosition = 0;

for ($x=0;$x<=$arrLength;$x++){
    if ($searchFirstName == $readByLineArray[$x])
    {
        $searchFirstNameSuccess = 1;
        $x++;
        if ($searchLastName == $readByLineArray[$x])
        {
            $searchLastNameSuccess = 1;
            $currentArrayPosition = $x - 1;
        } else {
            $searchFirstNameSuccess = 0;
        }
    }


}

for ($y=0;$y<=7;$y++){
    echo "$readByLineArray[$currentArrayPosition]<br />";
    $currentArrayPosition++;
}





?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all your help!

Ben---

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` loop like this..

```
for ($x=0;$x<$arrLength;$x++){ //<--- Should be < and not <=
```

Say if your array count is 3 , so the array elements keys are arranged as `0,1,2`. When you put `<=` in the looping as condition , your code will check for an non-existent key with an index of `3`  which will thrown an `Undefined Offset` notice.

**`EDIT :`**

#### The easier way....

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$fileName = "addresses.txt";

// Get search string from submission
$searchFirstName = $_POST['searchFirstName'];
$searchLastName = $_POST['searchLastName'];
$searchFirstNameSuccess = 0;
$searchLastNameSuccess = 0;

foreach(file($fileName) as $recno=>$records)
{
    if(stripos($records,$searchFirstName)!==false && stripos($records,$searchLastName)!==false)
    {
        $searchFirstNameSuccess = 1;
        $searchLastNameSuccess = 1;
        echo "Match Found at Position : $recno";
        break;
      }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I seem to be having trouble with my if statements section as well. The previous adjustment fixed the previous issue but no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to be comparing successfully and for each line read in.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to do in this example, Seems like you can do it even more easier.

Comment: Sorry. I read your response wrong. I'm trying to get my nested IF statements to compare the $searchFirstName to $readByLineArray[$x]. It's basically reading in names and addresses that have been written to a txt file and comparing to a search string to output just that person's name and address. I know a database would be simpler but I don't have that luxury and am trying to create something similar using just a text document.

Comment: So what you are doing is.. checking for the first name and last name in the array line by line and if a match found you should break from array  right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try foreach :-

```
foreach ($readByLineArray as $temp){
if ($searchFirstName == $temp)
{
    $searchFirstNameSuccess = 1;
    $x++;
    if ($searchLastName == $temp)
    {
        $searchLastNameSuccess = 1;

    } else {
        $searchFirstNameSuccess = 0;
    }
}
}
```